# Name for second mail accounts used only for unimportant websites to avoid being spammed

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title suggests, what is the name or the best way of referring to the second mail accounts many users on the internet open only for unimportant websites in order to avoid being spammed.

Disposable mail addresses are another thing, and spam mail accounts is too generic and would conflict with thousand of results searches for "how to avoid spam on my mail account".

EDIT:
They also are not throwaway addresses or temporary emails because people use them for extended periods of time and even forever as "unofficial email" just for unimportant websites.

Comment: The term is *throwaway*.

Comment: fake mail id's?

Comment: It can also be called a [*junk email address*](http://www.ricksdailytips.com/junk-email-address/) or a [*fake email address*.](http://www.komando.com/cool-sites/8091/avoid-spam-with-a-fake-email-address)

Comment: They are not throwaway actually, people use them as a secondary mail address but only for spam for extended periods and even forever. It simply is an unofficial email.

Comment: nice work Reg !

Answer (score 3):

I call mine my 'secondary' email address. 'Auxiliary' might also suit the purpose, since the concepts of *supplementary*, *helpful*, and *kept in reserve* are implied by its definition.

Comment: Here's a curiosity. Some folks don't realise, if you add "plus number" on you email, on most services it **usually still works**.  So, if you are john@hotmail.com or john@company.com, usually, john+2@hotmail.com or john+2@company.com .. will also work.  Use any number. It's very handy if you are, say, testing an app or website.

Comment: "secondary" seems to be about right.

Comment: Regarding the plus sign in the address, this is properly called an [**address tag**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags), less commonly a sub-address. The **+** character is expressly permitted in email addresses, as explained by [RFC 3696](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696#section-3), so rest easy that anyone who doesn't support it is *wrong*.

Answer (score 3):

Some people refer to these as a *spambox*, a portmanteau of spam and inbox. I don't have a reference for this as more sources assume you're asking about a spam or junk mail folder, so you just have to take this as an anecdote.

Note that there is a temporary email service called [spambox.us](http://spambox.us/en_US/) that acts as an auto-expiring auxiliary email address (like [10-minute-mail](http://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html) but more configurable and auto-forwarding to an email you provide). However, I maintain that this is a newer usage of the term spambox (as spambox.us was [registered in 2006](http://www.whois.net/whois/spambox.us)).

Answer (score 1):

Your *public* email address, which you use for accounts that are likely to sell your address, in contrast to your *private* email address, which you give only to your friends.

Comment: public and private seems a good way to describe them

Answer (score 0):

I know it as an "email alias."

My email service provides me with a primary email address and allows several additional "aliases" attached to that account.

I am able to configure my mail client to send email from any of those email aliases, which, occasionally, is handy.

Comment: If mail addressed to one of your aliases goes into your primary mailbox, then (I believe) this isn't what the question is asking for.

Comment: By Scott, I think you're right. Thanks for clearing that up. Okay then, I suppose it should be called a "bogus" or "dummy" email address.

Answer (score 0):

It think it is: "pseudo Email"

pseudo acts as something which pretends to be there.